# Regex match tags like @Joe but not email addresses

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I want to get all the tags (e.g. @Joe) in a string, but avoid email address (e.g. dave@example.com).

So in:

```
@Joe hello! @Dave's email address is dave@example.com
```

I want to only match @Joe and @Dave .

The regex I'm trying is

```
preg_match_all("([ ^]@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)", $comment, $atMatches);
```

But this only matches @Dave (after removing leading space).

Comment: The carat symbol inside the square brackets is a NOT instead of "start here". Also, that won't match `@Joe` if `@Joe` is at the beginning of the string due to the space in your first set of brackets.

Comment: A caret inside a character class is just a caret if it's not the first character in the class. `/[^a-z]/` is *not a lower case letter*, while `/[a-z^]/` is *a lower-case letter or a caret.* A non-whitespace character is just `/\S/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `\B` (not a word boundry) [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) to exclude the matches that have a word (like "dave" in the example text) before it. Something like:

```
preg_match_all("/\B(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", $comment, $atMatches);
```

By the way, you're not using proper delimiters in your syntax.

Comment: \b matches `@example` in my above example, whereas \B (not word boundry) matches `@Joe` and `@Dave` as I'd like. Why is it \B and not \b as you said in your example!?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. \B is actually what you are looking for, as you want to exclude matches that have the boundary of a word (in this case, "dave") attached to it. I'll edit my example.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should match `@Joe` and `@Dave` while ignoring the `'s` and email addresses:

```
(^@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})|(\s@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})

// ^@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}      matches @Name at the beginning of the line
// \s@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}     matches @Names that are preceded by a space (i.e. not an email address)
```

Comment: Better written as `/(?:^|\s)(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

Well that sounds very similar to a Twitter regex...

You could try editing the following example from [here](http://granades.com/2009/04/06/using-regular-expressions-to-match-twitter-users-and-hashtags/).

```
function linkify_tweet($tweet) {
    $tweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/',
        '\1@<a href="http://www.twitter.com/\2">\2</a>',
        $tweet);
    return preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/',
        '\1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>',
        $tweet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will match your example, ignoring e-mails and " ' "

```
preg_match_all("/(^|\s)(@.*?)['\s]/", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: `[^(\s')]` matches any character that's not `(` or `)` or `'` or whitespace; is that really what you meant?